# jQuery undefined in 1.2 stable jquery.mobile.js

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have updated jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js to jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js. I am getting jQuery undefined error.
In the previous beta version, I have modified the js as

```
(function(jQuery) {
// beta version code here..
})(custom.jquery);
```

where custom.jquery is defined as

```
custom.jquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

in the jquery.js

I have done similar wrapping in the stable 1.2 js and got the undefined error.
Without wrapping also got the same error.
Please advice me.